# Can I use findFiles without script tag in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Is there a way, in a Jenkins declarative pipeline, to write next code without the script tag?

```
script {
  foundFiles = findFiles(glob: "directory/NoConfig*.zip")
  noConfigFilePath = foundFiles[0].toString()
}

unzip zipFile: noConfigFilePath,
  dir: "otherDirectory",
  quiet: true
```

Putting it outside script tags doesn't work.

I need this code because unzip doesn't take any wildcards in the zipFile argument.

Answer (score 0):

What actually requires the `script` block is not the `findFiles` keyword but the fact your are declaring a variable (`foundFiles` and `noConfigFilePath`), which can't be done in pure declarative syntax and requires scripted pipeline context (the script directive).

To avoid the need of a `script` block you will need to avoid the variable declaration, and you can do so by using the `findFiles` in a single line with the call to `unzip`:

```groovy
stage('Unzip File'){
    steps {
        unzip zipFile: "${findFiles(glob: 'directory/NoConfig*.zip')[0].path}",
              dir: "otherDirectory",
              quiet: true
    }
}
```